# pyqt5 keypressevent 'something i want to know

Tags: python, events, pyqt5, keypress

[How PyQt5 keyPressEvent works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45308101/how-pyqt5-keypressevent-works)

this code really work but i want know somthing

the main window (as the class) it inherited (QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow)

as i go to QMainWindow.py there are keyPressEvent(self, *args, **kwargs)

so i modified qwindow.py ex)

```
def keyPressEvent(self, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
    print("this is test")
    pass
```

but when i run the program  it doesn't work

i want to modify qmainwindow.py so it can work any sysytem without inherted it

is there any idea?

Comment: QMainWindow.py ?, is a bad practice that a file is called like a class that is part of a library (it can bring you silent problems in the future), on the other hand that means it does not work, check the [tour], read [ask] and also provide a [mcve]

Comment: thankyou i really use that method but really curious about this thing... and im new here and..im not good at english so it takes time to accustom how to ask.. really sorry